# How do i access label text in piechart created using D3.js?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, d3.js

I am accessing label text in piechart like this

```
if($scope.data[0].label === 'Successful  Calls')
    {
        buildChart("#chart1", $scope.data);
    }
    else
    {
        buildChart("#chart2", $scope.data);
    }
```

its working fine but when i run test cases written in parent directive gets failed.If i remove if else block then tests are passing. 
this error i got

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.data[0]')
```

can i access the label text using some other method because ,method i using already creating problem for test cases.

Comment: I suppose you are loading the $scope.data from an external source. During unit tests, are you emulating the same behavior ?

Comment: yes i loaded $scope.data using d3.js but i don't know why its failing test cases that is for parent directive

Comment: @Rabi can we access the label text in data using a different approach other than i currently using?

Comment: can you add your unit test case here ?

Comment: @Rabi sorry but the issue is with the method i using for accessing the label text in data is there some other method to check the label text and if that match with string which i given then build chart is called?

Comment: I think, the problem is not the way you are accessing the label text. without anyback ground info, this is my wild guess - First, you are loading json data using d3 and populating $scope.data (and you are doing the same on your unit tests also, which is not recommended. you should actually mock network calls.)  Second, you are trying to check the label filed before the data is loaded . hence you get such undefined error. If this is the case, I guess I have the solution else I'm handicapped without more details.